# PHP нужна помощь в разделении строки на элементы

Tags: php

Есть обычный текстовый документ t.txt. В нем записаны 3 числа. Как с помощью PHP достать из файла числа.И выполнить цикл.
Пример кода

```
<?php
$file = fopen("t.txt", "r+");
$data = fgets($file);
$array = explode(' ', $data); 
list($value1, $value2, $value3) = $data;
$i = 1;
while ($i <= value3) {
$result ='';
if ($i%$value1==0) {
    $result .='F';} 
if ($i%$$value2==0) {
    $result .='B';}
if (!$result) {
    $result = $i;} 
    $i++;
}
$test = fwrite($file, $result); 
if ($test) echo 'Данные в файл успешно занесены.';
else echo 'Ошибка при записи в файл.';
fclose($file);
```

Содержание t.txt

```
1 2 20
```

Comment: я ни чего не понял, что необходимо получить в итоге? перезаписать файл? дописать? просто итерировать данные?

Comment: Нужно взять числа из файла и подставить в цикл value1=1, value2=2, value3=20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой пример.
Достаём данные из файла.

```
 $data = file('file/path/t.txt');
```

Разделяем данные.

```
 $values = explode(' ', $data);
 list($value1, $value2, $value3) = $values
```

Выполняем цикл и действия. Цикл будет идти от 0 до значения `$value3` А именно до 20 включительно.

```
 for($i = 0; $i <= $value3; $i++) {
     //тут код
 }
```